# Reference to an element by id alone, no document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

I am currently working on a mobile site using jquery mobile and I noticed something interesting (to me anyway, as I am still new to js). Inside a function, you can reference an element with just the id.

This is the test code I used (on chrome 22.0.x, firefox 16.0.1, and safari 5.1.7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onload="tt()">
    <div id="abc">Test</div>
    <a id="cba">Test2</a>
  </body>
  <Script>
    function tt() {
        console.log(abc);
        abc.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return cba;
    }
  </Script>
</html>
```

No getElementById, no jquery selector, just the id. Has it always been this way? If so, is this a good practice and why does this work? I am thinking function must have a context, but where is it, is it the page?

Any insight would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: To answer your question, that sounds like a _horrible_ habit to start.

Comment: Thanks guys. Great response, I'll stick with the good old getElementById :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are really doing:

```
window.abc;
```

This is something that IE started that was really a poor design choice.

See this [great answer to a very very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here#answer-3434388)

It's really a duplicate but the title does not reflect this.

Try this line in your console to see what I mean.

```
(function(){ console.log(this); })(); // logs the Window object
```